# Print datetime in Windows cmd

Tags: linux, windows, bash

In Linux I do `date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"` to print a date and time label. How do I get the same in Windows?

I found that `date /t` returns `25/02/2016`. But I would like to have it formatted like `20160225155958`.

Answer (score 8):

It can be done, but it's not as neat and tidy as that:

```
echo %date:~-4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%
```

This for me returns:

[image]

Note this is locale specific, and it's a bit of a hack around really. It's simply a concatenation of:

- Last 4 chars of DATE
- Mid of Date, 2 chars starting from char 3
- Mid of Date, 2 chars starting from char 0
- Mid of Time, 2 chars starting from char 0
- Mid of Time, 2 chars starting from char 3
- Mid of Time, 2 chars starting from char 6

Comment: See my answer for a locale independent solution ;)

Comment: I see your answer doesn't return local time ...

Comment: @DavidPostill ? Yes it does, only around 5 seconds out from when I took the screenshot. The big clock is my local time ;)

Comment: Ah. OK. I looked at the posting date which matched UK time ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill Don't worry it got me aswell, if it wasn't for the fact it was dark when I took the screenshot it confused me a little at first glance! +1 for your answer, should really familiarise myself with what wmic can provide.

Comment: Thanks ;) `wmic` is powerful but it's a pain to parse the output. You have to know `for /f` pretty well and the variable substring manipulation as well if you need to reformat the output.

Comment: I used 
> echo %date:~-4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2% %time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2%:%time:~6,2%
to have it formatted as YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

Answer (score 4):

#### I would like to have it formatted like 20160225155958

> which is the output format of running:
>
> `date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"`
>
> on Linux.

Using `%date%` to provide a solution is, as pointed out in another answer, dependent on the OS Locale, Regional, and Language settings.

Using `wmic`, on the other hand, works independently of OS Locale, Language or the user's chosen date format (Control Panel/Regional).

The following batch file uses `wmic` to retrieve the date and (local) time in the OP's specified format, so doesn't suffer the disadvantage of a solution using `%date%`.

**getdate.cmd:**

```
@echo off
setlocal
rem use findstr to strip blank lines from wmic output
for /f "usebackq skip=1 tokens=1-6" %%g in (`wmic Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Hour^,Minute^,Month^,Second^,Year ^| findstr /r /v "^$"`) do (
  set _day=00%%g
  set _hours=00%%h
  set _minutes=00%%i
  set _month=00%%j
  set _seconds=00%%k
  set _year=%%l
  )
rem pad with leading zeros
set _month=%_month:~-2%
set _day=%_day:~-2%
set _hh=%_hours:~-2%
set _mm=%_minutes:~-2%
set _ss=%_seconds:~-2%
set _date=%_year%%_month%%_day%%_hh%%_mm%%_ss%
echo %_date%
endlocal
```

The above batch file is a modified version of the example in [getdate](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-getdate.html)

**Output**:

```
F:\test>date /t && time /t
25/02/2016
16:49

F:\test>getdate
20160225164929
F:\test>
```

**Cywin for comparison**:

```
DavidPostill@Hal /f/test
$ date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"
20160225164938
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [getdate](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-getdate.html) - Display the date and time independent of OS Locale, Language or the users chosen date format (Control Panel/Regional).
- [variables](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) - Extract part of a variable (substring).
- [wmic](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) - Windows Management Instrumentation Command.