# Different result from command line prog when run by Task Scheduler

Tags: windows, command-line, scheduled-tasks

I call the following program from within another command line prog...

```
:: NT_getdate.cmd    return yumd-date in var='ymd'
@echo on
setlocal
for /F "tokens=2,3,4 delims=/ " %%g in ('echo.^|date /t') do (
    set dd=%%g
    set mm=%%h
    set yy=%%i
)
endlocal& set ymd=%yy%%mm%%dd%
```

When I run the progam from within command line ymd is returned as "20160501" which is what I want.

When I run the top program from Task Scheduler the result I get is "1605"

Any ideas?

Comment: my guess is that the user running the command via task scheduler has a different environment than your desktop user does. have you tried scheduling the task under your own user?

Comment: have you tried just running `date /t` and then the pause command  and compare the formats between batch file within cmd, and task scheduler

Answer (score 0):

#### I would like to have the date formatted like 20160501

> When I run the progam from within command line ymd is returned as "20160501" which is what I want.
>
> When I run the top program from Task Scheduler the result I get is "1605"

Using `%date%` to provide a solution is dependent on the OS Locale, Regional, and Language settings. This explains why you are getting different outputs.

Using `wmic`, on the other hand, works independently of OS Locale, Language or the user's chosen date format (Control Panel/Regional).

The following batch file uses `wmic` to retrieve the date and (local) time in the OP's specified format, so doesn't suffer the disadvantage of a solution using `%date%`.

**GetDate.cmd:**

```
@echo off
setlocal
rem use findstr to strip blank lines from wmic output
for /f "usebackq skip=1 tokens=1-3" %%g in (`wmic Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Month^,Year ^| findstr /r /v "^$"`) do (
  set _day=00%%g
  set _month=00%%h
  set _year=%%i
  )
  rem pad with leading zeros
  set _month=%_month:~-2%
  set _day=%_day:~-2%
  set _date=%_year%%_month%%_day%
  echo %_date%
endlocal
```

Notes:

- The above batch file is a modified version of the example in [getdate](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-getdate.html).
- It is easily tweaked to meet your exact needs.
- If you decide you also need the time (hours, minutes and seconds) then see my answer [Print datetime in Windows cmd](https://superuser.com/a/1045459/337631)

**Output**:

```
F:\test>date /t
01/05/2016

F:\test>GetDate
20160501

F:\test>
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [getdate](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-getdate.html) - Display the date and time independent of OS Locale, Language or the users chosen date format (Control Panel/Regional).
- [variables](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) - Extract part of a variable (substring).
- [wmic](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) - Windows Management Instrumentation Command.