# How to write to a file over network sharing center

Tags: networking, batch

I am a fairly novice batch coder but I know most of the ropes... Except... How do I write to a .txt file on another computer on my Network. As both computers are Windows, they allow for network and sharing center. So, I have made a program on another computer that is supposed to write the time (echo %time% >> time.txt) to a .txt in MY COMPUTER. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: @CharlieRB batch programming is on topic here (as other other scripting languages) but we do expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. Note I would expect to already know this with your rep.

Comment: Batch programming seems at that edge of being off topic. No argument from me, so I retracted my vote to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
@echo off
TITLE Time
call "\\otherpc\c$\users\%username%\Documents\program.bat"
exit
```

That would call that program on that computer

In the program you would need to make sure you have

```
echo %time%>>"\\currentpc\c$\path\
```

Obviously, adjust the paths as needed.

If you are planning to run this more than once, you would overwrite that file. You can solve this by perhaps renaming the file to the time. Here is some code you could use:

```
set Source=H:\LOS\log
set Target=H:\LOS\log
FOR /f "tokens=1-8 delims=/.:- " %%A in ("%date% %time%") DO (
   SET Month=%%B
   SET Day=%%C
   SET Year=%%D
   SET Hours=%%E
   SET Minutes=%%F
   SET Seconds=%%G
   SET All=%%B-%%C-%%D_%%E-%%F-%%G
)
if not exist "%Target%\%Year%" md "%Target%\%Year%"
FOR %%i IN ("%Source%\login.txt") DO ^
COPY "%%i" "%Target%\%Year%\%All%_%%~Ni_%COMPUTERNAME%.txt"
```

You could try something like this if you get Access is denied:

```
net use x: \\remotepc\c$\path user:username password /p:no
call x:\path
other code here
net use x: /d
```

Comment: Using `date` and `time` gives locale dependent results. You should use `wmic` to get the date and time in a locale independent way. See my answer [Print datetime in Windows cmd](http://superuser.com/a/1045459) for the correct way to do this.

Comment: There is no comments button under InterLinked's response because I don't have enough reputation.. Just know that this is for him... I tried the call command becuase that was what I was after but I just get "Access is denied" when I put in all of the correct replacements and are calling an existing file. So what do I do?

Comment: You need permission to access the remote PC. Try browsing to the location in File Explorer. You should be prompted for credentials. Login as you would on that PC and check remember credentials. This is the easiest way to get it to work. Make sure you can get to the file in Explorer first, then try the call command

Comment: I never had a problem with going into that folder before with file explorer and I don't now however I tried going into Control Panel > Network and Sharing Center > Change Advanced Sharing Settings > All Networks > Password Protected Sharing > Off               Still "Access is denied", not even "The system could not find the path specified" just "Access is denied"....

Comment: If you open the Run dialog and paste in the path you are trying to access, does it work. Otherwise, try adding username and password to your batch file

Comment: how do I add a username and password to the file? and the run works...