# filename with date and time as title?

Tags: filenames, netstat

trying to setup a task in task scheduler to run every hour, I'm having trouble finding a way to add the date and time to the filename, looking for something concise like a one liner, or if needed, just something that works that i can put in a batch file, so far the idea is something like this:
**netstat /anob >%USERPROFILE%\OneDrive\scripts\netstat\netstatlog_("%H%M%S").txt**

this of course doesnt work as intended, but you see what i'm basically trying to do i hope

Comment: See my answer [Print datetime in Windows cmd](http://superuser.com/a/1045459)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `%time%` and extract individual parts from it.

For example, if `echo %time%` displays `21:41:30.85`.

- Hour = `%time:~0,2%`
- Minute = `%time:~3,2%`
- Second = `%time:~6,2%`

Then, `echo %time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%` will output `214130`.

In you case, a one liner will look like so:

`ping 8.8.8.8 > %USERPROFILE%\ping_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.log`

Similar operation can be applied to `%date%` to extract individual parts from current date.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to have the script create a new temporary variable(s) and then set the time/date into it after it's been properly formatted.  Then have set your script to use the temporary variable.  For a detailed explanation, follow the instructions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-to-get-current-datetime-on-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format-for-us) link.